# Use different css based on content of element?

Tags: css

This is a theoretical question about the capabilities of CSS.

I know normal practice is to change this server side, but I was wondering if it's possible to use alternate css based on the content of an element. For example if a table division element contains a 0 style it one colour.

```
<td class="result">0</td>
```

And anything higher than 0 style an alternate colour

```
<td class="result">1</td>

<td class="result">5</td>
```

Comment: hmm don't think you can achieve this with pure css.

Comment: Nope, you'd need JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

A way this can be achieved is by using HTML5 data attributes, but this requires you to slightly modify your markup (which usually isn't a problem if it's dynamically generated):

HTML:

```
<td data-result="1">1</td>
```

CSS:

```
td[data-result="1"] { ... }
```

[Working JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/gehurisivipe/1/edit)

For a full browser support, it's better to use JavaScript.

Comment: I guess if I applied this to result of 0 instead of 1 then anything other than 0 would inherit the normal styling

Comment: Correct. Try it out with different CSS